# Scala value object hierarchies

Tags: scala, oop, data-modeling

I'm new to Scala and trying to understand how I should be modeling these objects.

The goal here is to have an object that will be stored into a database. The data to store will come from a POST. The post does not contain all of the data that will be persisted.

The OO side of me says to make a base class with the common fields. Extend it represent the data that is posted, and extend that to represent the object that is persisted. However, it seems that case classes are used for this sort of thing, and case class inheritance is discouraged/deprecated/buggy, so I'm not quite sure what I *should* be doing.

Also, the repetition feels very... wrong.

I am hoping someone a bit more experienced can offer some insight on how to approach this.

```
abstract class TestBase(val someField: String)

case class TestPost(override val someField: String) extends TestBase(someField)

case class Test(testId: String, override val someField: String) extends TestBase(someField)
```

Also, if I did continue with this approach, how would you copy fields from a TestPost instance to a Test instance?

Answer (score 0):

although you are doing OOP and you can in Scala you should also be pressing on the functional way of doing things, functional programming states your objects should be immutable and case classes that's what they are for, they represent the value object pattern built right in the language. My advice would be to use composition instead.

```
case class A(field : Field)
case class B(a : A, moreFields : Fields)
```

I am not sure how you are trying to persist things to a database.

Comment: Let's say we're using Mongo, and I want this to be stored in the collection:
    {
        testId: 1,
        someField: "anything"
    }

But the POST JSON will not contain testId. Should I just not try to have an object that represents the POST?

Comment: what about {testId: 1, {somefield: "anything"}} I would not sweat about having front end and back end using same objects more likely your post object is just a DTO